Best way to fix data inconsistency
If you have a column in your table that contains inconsistent data for destinations, for example some may be "New York", some "New York, USA", "NY", etc. for different records, and there are already thousands of records, what is the best way to normalize them?

It's 2024 now, so I guess the answer is "Get an LLM to do it". Otherwise, ask your boss if there are any underutilized interns in your org for you to borrow to tweak data rows, one-by-one, in Excel, for weeks or months until they quit.

I think , firstly you have to decide which one the data you want. after that check if that column has a related with another data. if no relate to another data maybe you can backup data and delete them

First you need to decide on which canonical form you want them to be represented as. Some may be ambiguous - particularly two letter abbreviations. For me NY is North Yorkshire... It gets much harder where multiple counties have the same city name in. eg in the UK there is a Salford city in Lancashire and a Salford village in Oxfordshire by the same name.

This sounds like a job for an UPDATE query.

Best solution is to fix your data at source, if possible, by ensuring that data can only be entered consistently.
If you have a large number of columns to fix and the data in them is constantly changing then there is no good solution to fixing them downstream. If there is a limited number of columns and a limited number of variations then build a reference table based on the data you have and use that to drive your update statements:



INPUT VALUE
CLEANSED VALUE




New York
New York


New York, USA
New York


NY
New York




Can you advise how to build the reference table for each variation of the destination? I mean there is apparently hundreds of destinations and each of them has few variations already stored in the db

You just add the all the variations you have to the INPUT VALUE column and the value you want to change them to in the CLEANSED VALUE column. In the real world you'd probably want to have a "TYPE" column to distinguish groups e.g. a CITY type for all the records that translate CITY values, a TITLE type for Mr, Ms, Dr etc. As I mentioned at the start of my answer, if you have a large number of columns/values to clean, building/maintaining this table and using it to cleanse you data is not a trivial exercise

You can add another option for select country or city like amazon ebay etc. there is city option for this problem. In the other side the string manupulation will take long time anyway. If you need string manupulation search keys and change names from IDE etc.
Search New York than change all to NY. ide can do this just 1 click. But this is not sustainable. You can use AI model IF you trust ofcourse.

Figure out the root cause of the problem you are trying to solve.
Inconsistent data is annoying but not necessarily a problem, for example the post office may still deliver it.
So ask yourself: What is the actual problem here?  The inconsistent addresses can be a cause but what problem do they actually cause?
Once you have a good answer to this you'll then know which approaches to pursue in fixing it.
